# Autofill based on list and value of a cell

Tags: formula, libreoffice-calc

I'm making a spreadsheet to help me with my personal accounting. I'm trying to create a formula in LibreOffice Calc that will search in a given cell for a number of different text strings and if found return a text string.

[image: Screen shot]

For example, the formula should search for "burger" or "McDonalds" in `$C6` and likewise then return "Food" to `$E6`. It should not be case sensitive. And needs partially to match strings as well as in the case of Burger King. I need it to be able to search for other keywords and return those values as well, like "AutoZone" and return "Auto" and NewEgg and return "Electronics".

I've had a tough time finding any kind of solution to this and the closet I could get was with a `MATCH` formula but once I nested it in an `IF` it would not work. I've also tried nested `IF` with `OR`; not joy on either.

*Examples:*

```
=IF(OR(D10="*hulu*",D10="*netflix*",D10="*movie*",D10="*theature*",D10="*stadium*",D10="*google*music*")=1,"Entertainment",IF(OR(D10="*taco*",D10="*burger*",D10="*mcdonald*",D10="*dq*",D10="*tokyo*",D10="*wendy*",D10="*cafe*",D10="*wing*",D10="*tropical*",D10="*kfc*",D10="*olive*",D10="*caesar*",D10="*costa*vida*",D10="*Carl*",D10="*in*n*out*",D10="*golden*corral*",D10="*nija*",D10="*arby*",D10="*Domino*",D10="*Subway*",D10="*Iggy*",D10="*Pizza*Hut*",D10="*Rumbi*",D10="*Custard*",D10="*Jimmy*")=1,"Food",IF(OR(D10="*autozone*",D10="*Napa*",D10="*OREILLY*")=1,"AUTO","-")))
```

I can create a different table and make a lookup reference so another way to put this is I need something that does the opposite of what `VLOOKUP` and `HLOOKUP` do and return the header value for any data matching in given columns.

*Something like:*

```
=IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A1,B3:B99))),B2,IF(NOT(ISNA(MATCH(A1,C3:C99))),c2,0))
```

If `A1` was the test and `B2` and `C2` were the headers and it was searching below those.

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le).

Comment: `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"hulu","netflix"},D10)),"Entertainment",If(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(…))))` and so forth, you can add to the array inside the `{}`.  It will find if the words are in the cell string without wildcards.  It is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Thank you!!! I think this is exactly what I've been looking for.

I tried to apply it to my actual situation and the "Entertainment" worked. So I changed the code and now the second category "Food" did it not work and gave me a ERR:504. 

Here is exact code I used: 
`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"hulu","netflix","movie","theature","stadium"},F73)),"Entertainment",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"taco","burger","mcdonald","dq","tokyo","wendy","cafe","wing","tropical","kfc","olive","caesar","vida","carl","corral","nija","arby","domino","subway","iggy","pizza","rumbi","custard","jimmy"},F73)),"Food"),"-")`

Comment: Okay I figured out what I was doing wrong in the syntax but now that the formula is right it is only finding matches to the first search in the list. 
For Example, this code:
`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"hulu";"netflix";"movie";"theature";" stadium"},G150)),"Entertainment",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"burger","taco","vida","cafe","wing","dairy","mcdonald","wendy","kfc","pizza","carl","domino","ceaser","olive","jimmy","custard","subway","arby"},G150)),"Food","-"))`
Will only return "Entertainment" if it sees hulu but not movies or any others but it will work for burger and return "Food" but not for taco etc.

Comment: @JaredW82 another way, and I did test this one, `=IF(SUM(LEN(G150)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(G150),{"hulu";"netflix";"movie";"theature";" stadium"},"")))>0,"Entertainment",IF(SUM(LEN(G150)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(G150),{"burger","taco","vida","caf‌​e","wing","dairy","mcdonald","wendy","kfc","pizza","carl","domino","ceaser","oliv‌​e","jimmy","custard","subway","arby"},"")))>0,"Food","-"))`  Make sure you confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comments, try this:

```
=IF(SUM(LEN(G150)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(G150),{"hulu","netflix","movie","theater"," stadium"},"")))>0,"Entertainment",IF(SUM(LEN(G150)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(G150),{"burger","taco","vida","caf‌​e","wing","dairy","mcdonald","wendy","kfc","pizza","carl","domino","ceaser","oliv‌​e","jimmy","custard","subway","arby"},"")))>0,"Food",IF(SUM(LEN(G150)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(G150),{"autozone","Napa","oreilly"},"")))>0,"AUTO","-")))
```

It is an Array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this various ways using INDEX/MATCH/VLOOKUP formulae. Just a couple of caveats: I am using Excel, and never used Libre so hope this works; and, you will need a mapping table that maps MacDonalds to Food, Google Music to Entertainment and so on (for all the cases possible).

Let's assume your mapping table in your screenshot is A6 to E9.

The formula in E10 `=vlookup(C10,$C$6:$E$9,3,0)`

Explanation: it looks up C10 (Burger King) in the table $C$6:$E$9 and result is the 3rd column (E is 3rd column from C, where C10 was looked up) in that table. The 0 will give you an exact match, if you want a partial match then enter 1 there.

Note: if your mapping table is in say columns G and H (Service name in G and Type of Service in H), AND you are unsure how many entries it will have, a mod to the formula is `=vlookup(C10,$G:$H,2,0)` OR `=vlookup(C10,$G:$H,2,1)` for a partial match. Here, 3 is replaced by 2 because H is the 2nd column from G where C10 will be looked up.

EDIT: Doing `VLOOKUP` with `INDEX` and `MATCH` functions for an approximate match of text - this could be the solution you are looking at in your last comment(?)

Two things needed to be done. a.Reference table entries, b.applying the `INDEX`/`MATCH` function.

Part a - in your reference table, you will have to make entries between 2*s for the value to be looked up. The way you mention in your example in the Qn `*movie*`,`*wendy*`,etc. **That's really the trick that enables us to lookup by cell reference.** Corresponding return values like Entertainment/Food/etc need to be their own full words. Let's assume you have this table prepared in columns G6:H26 (G-lookup value, H-return value)

Part b - In you cell F6 (as per your screenshot), you can try this formula `=INDEX($H$6:$H$26,MATCH(C6,$G$6:$G$26,0))`
That really just is the replacement formula for VLOOKUP using INDEX/MATCH.

As your values stored in column G are in *s, the cell C6 in the MATCH formula will do a partial read.

Comment: Thank you! I tried using a `vlookup` but the only problem is that:  
(1) I'd have to have a big table somewhere because my actual data has 74 possible 'Type' categories to match a list of a possible 100, and counting, 'Transaction's.  
(2) There is not the same number of matches for the 'Food' Type as there are for the 'Auto" type. Does this matter with `vlookup`?  
(3) When I tried using `vlookup` before I could only get exact matches in the table. Maybe I was doing something wrong so I'll play with it again because the advantage of course is that the list can be dynamically updated.  
Thanks

Comment: Sure. For point no (2) - there is no problems if one type of entries exceed another. The only reason to suggest a lookup formula is I prefer keeping my data separate to my formulae - as against containing all the data (e.g.burger/netflix/etc) in the formula itself. It's probably fine as your sheet is not going to run into 100s of thousands of rows, but for bigger data, it will start making a difference. (Just a tip) FYI only, to have such a table separate is similar to relational structure of fetching data. Else @Scott's logic is spot on.

Comment: `vlookup` is returning the 1st value that has only 1 letter matching when I choose the 1 sort order.  There has got to be a better way to do this using the `MATCH` & `INDEX` Functions. I'm not savvy enough to figure this out. I need to to reference a whole part of the word, like 'burger' as in 'Burger King' search value in `$C` column & match it to the value 'Food' in a given table.

I'd prefer a table, so I can easily updated it but `vlookup` is only giving me exact or the first one with a similar letter. If not possible I'll use the `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({...` if I can figure out the syntax.

Comment: Have suggested a mod - is that what you were looking for? I decided to provide the edit, as you seemed open to creating a reference table for this activity. If you have a reference table prepared as mentioned in the Edit, you can use the VLOOKUP formula as well I think (not tested it myself when posting this answer)